# Fiddler Running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: wcf, soap, windows-server-2008, fiddler

I have an ARM embedded processor that talks to a .net WCF SOA (SOAP) web service application.  The ARM device is remotely located and web service is hosted in a WS2k8 cloud server. I am having some protocol issues with the ARM code and would like to run Fiddler on my WS2k8 machine to observer the SOAP exchange between the embedded device and the web service application.  I installed Fiddler Web Debugger V4.4.8 on the server but it does not capture any http requests.  I know the ARM device is talking to my web services as it responds to several good SOAP exchanges.  Anyone know how to set up Fiddler to work in the configuration I have explained?

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler is a proxy, it captures any requests sent to it. If your ARM device supports a proxy, then point its proxy settings at the Fiddler endpoint on the Windows Server, port 8888. Also tick `Allow Remote Clients to Connect` in the Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections tab, and restart Fiddler.

If the client *doesn't* support configuring a proxy, you need to [Use Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/usefiddlerasreverseproxy).

Comment: I changed the ARM device send to port to 8888 and ticked "allow remote clients to connect".  I also opened up port 8888 on the firewall but still no connection.  The ARM device times out with an error "device socket connection timeout".  I might be missing something very basic here so assume I need more hand holding.

Comment: What URL specifically have you configured? Is the URL HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: The URL is HTTP.  I notice that when I bring up a browser on the server Fiddler gets HTTP packets.

Comment: Like I said, on the ARM device I am sending my HTTP packets to the web services IP address with port 8888 and the device sees nothing.  At least I think it sees nothing because the sockets open times out. I tried to implement Fiddler as a Reverse Proxy but again the ARM device could not open the socket.  Understand the ARM device is an embedded device and I have very few tools to debug this kind of problem on the ARM side.  Getting Fiddler to capture the HTTP frames on the server side would help tremendously with debug.

Comment: If you use a *different* PC to send HTTP requests to `http://FiddlerIP:8888/` are those requests shown?

Comment: Your suggestion led me to the problem.  I used another computer as you suggested and did not see any fiddler captures.  I am using Amazon's E2C Cloud Services running Windows Server 2008R2.  I had properly provisioned the server firewall rules to open port 8888.  However, Once I saw no traffic I figured the request was getting blocked to my server instance.  I checked and the Amazon instance was blocking all of my ports except for port 80 and a few others.  I opened the instance port and everything started to work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

They way I fixed it was to set in the client application to use a proxy (http://127.0.0.1:8888) so now the calls are redirected to fiddler and fiddler call the services, so I can see the traffic. Hope it helps someone